# creating a function for a while loop

Tags: php, function, loops, while-loop

Hi I'm trying to make this code into a function and I am struggling to get it right. I'm calling the function page with an include its just making it a function that seems to be the problem.

```
<?php

        $sql= "SELECT `username`, `agent_name`, `building_number`, `building_name`, `street`, `town`, `post_code`, `email`, `description`, `profile`, `phone` 
               FROM `users` 
               ORDER BY `username` ASC";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);




    while ($user = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<div class="results">';
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><h2>';?><a href ="<?php echo $user['username'];?>"> <?php echo $user['agent_name'];'</a></h2></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
```

My attempt is:

```
<?php
function test ($sql, $result){

    $sql= "SELECT `username`, `agent_name`, `building_number`, `building_name`, `street`, `town`, `post_code`, `email`, `description`, `profile`, `phone` 
           FROM `users` 
           ORDER BY `username` ASC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}



while (test($user)) {
     $user= mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo '<div class="results">';
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><h2>';?><a href ="<?php echo $user['username'];?>"> <?php echo $user['agent_name'];'</a></h2></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: what do you want to do? why are you making it as a function?

Comment: first of all **mysql_** functions are deprecated. So use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: i am teaching myself php and i thought it would add more security than just allowing someone access to the the sql

Comment: A function in PHP has nothing to do wih security of accessing sql

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try it all in your function. Have you function just do a 'function'. In this case it may get passed some parameters and it returns results (fetched from the database). I would then have the function return the data as an array. You can then do a 'foreach' statement for the array and style it into a table onwards from that.

Answer (score 0):

That should do the job, **BUT** it's really bad practise:

```
<?php
function test (){

    $sql= "SELECT `username`, `agent_name`, `building_number`, `building_name`, `street`, `town`, `post_code`, `email`, `description`, `profile`, `phone` 
           FROM `users` 
           ORDER BY `username` ASC";

    return mysql_query($sql);

}



while ($user= mysql_fetch_array(test())) {
echo '<div class="results">';
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><h2>';?><a href ="<?php echo $user['username'];?>"> <?php echo $user['agent_name'];'</a></h2></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

why are u calling function...You can try like this...

```
    <?
     $start=$_GET["start"];
     if($start=="")
     $start=0;
     $max=50; //you can change this to number of records to display//
     $objTotalRS=mysql_query("SELECT * from users");
     $sqlcat="SELECT * FROM users Order by username asc limit $start,$max";
     $cat_data = mysql_query($sqlcat);
     ?>
```

In HTML

```
     <div class="results">
     <table>
     <tr>
     <td> User Name </td>
     <td> Agent Name </td>
     </tr>
     <? while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($cat_data)) { ?>
     <tr>
     <td><?=stripslashes($data["username"])?></td>
     <td><?=stripslashes($data["agent_name"])?></td>
     </tr>
     <?}?>
     </table>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function getUsers() {
    //assumed mysql_connect()
    $sql= "SELECT `username`, `agent_name`, `building_number`, `building_name`, `street`, `town`, `post_code`, `email`, `description`, `profile`, `phone` FROM `users` ORDER BY `username` ASC";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while (($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) != false) {
?>
<div class="results">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2><a href="<?php echo $row['username'];?>"><?php echo $row['agent_name'];' ?></a></h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<?
    }
}
//call it!
getUsers();

?>
```